# Getting output queue via FTP of a Mainframe (zOS)

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe, zos

I am working with my mainframe running jobs via FTP and retrieving the result (of the Held queue) too through the same canal. The problem is, I have the "output queue" where the same JOBnnnnn left other information, and those reports I can only see via ISPF (option G.O). Is there anyway to see this reports via FTP? I learn to do this with this link: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-zosbatchjavav/

Example of the link (ftp's commands):

```
C:\>ftp 192.168.152.2
Connected to 192.168.152.2.
220-FTPD1 IBM FTP CS V1R5 at p390.qld.isi.com.au, 04:26:27 on 2006-09-06.
220 Connection will close if idle for more than 5 minutes.
User (192.168.152.2:(none)): isielw
331 Send password please.
Password:
230 ISIELW is logged on.  Working directory is "ISIELW.".
ftp> quote SITE FILETYPE=JES
200 SITE command was accepted
ftp>
ftp> dir
200 Port request OK.
125 List started OK for JESJOBNAME=ISIELW*, JESSTATUS=ALL and JESOWNER=ISIELW
JOBNAME  JOBID    OWNER    STATUS CLASS
ISIELW   TSU00629 ISIELW   OUTPUT TSU      ABEND=522 3 spool files
ISIELW   TSU00609 ISIELW   OUTPUT TSU      ABEND=522 3 spool files
ISIELW   TSU00294 ISIELW   OUTPUT TSU      ABEND=522 3 spool files
ISIELW   TSU00250 ISIELW   OUTPUT TSU      ABEND=522 3 spool files
ISIELW   TSU00218 ISIELW   OUTPUT TSU      ABEND=522 3 spool files
ISIELW   TSU00199 ISIELW   OUTPUT TSU      ABEND=622 3 spool files
ISIELW   TSU00171 ISIELW   OUTPUT TSU      ABEND=522 3 spool files
250 List completed successfully.
ftp: 524 bytes received in 0.06Seconds 8.45Kbytes/sec.
ftp> dir TSU00629
200 Port request OK.
125 List started OK for JESJOBNAME=ISIELW*, JESSTATUS=ALL and JESOWNER=ISIELW
JOBNAME  JOBID    OWNER    STATUS CLASS
ISIELW   TSU00629 ISIELW   OUTPUT TSU      ABEND=522
--------
         ID  STEPNAME PROCSTEP C DDNAME   BYTE-COUNT
         001 JES2              K JESMSGLG       962
         002 JES2              K JESJCL       13983
         003 JES2              K JESYSMSG     17176
3 spool files
250 List completed successfully.
ftp: 340 bytes received in 0.03Seconds 10.63Kbytes/sec.
ftp>
```

If I wouldn't have JOBS, the message "No jobs found on Held queue" is displayed.

This is my current result:

```
230 CERVHM is logged on.  Working directory is "CER.".
ftp> quote site filetype=jes
200 SITE command was accepted
ftp> dir
200 Port request OK.
125 List started OK
CERVHM2   JOB01948  OUTPUT    4 Spool Files
CERVHM1   JOB03024  OUTPUT    3 Spool Files
250 List completed successfully.
ftp: 148 bytes recibidos en 0,02segundos 7,40a KB/s.
ftp> dir JOB01948
200 Port request OK.
125 List started OK
CERVHM2   JOB01948  OUTPUT    4 Spool Files
CERVHM1   JOB03024  OUTPUT    3 Spool Files
250 List completed successfully.
ftp: 148 bytes recibidos en 0,02segundos 7,05a KB/s.
ftp>
```

Regards!

P.D. I am new in mainframe's world, let me now if you don't understand the question. Also I made a Java program to do the same, but I have the same question.

Comment: The example you have shown is giving you held output. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Hello @Bill Woodger, are you familiar with ISPF? When I run a job I get the results in "Held queue" (option G.H) and other report for the same job in the "Ouput queue" (option G.O). The question is, How can i retrieve the output queue via FTP?

Comment: The example is showing you output jobs on the spool, the second dir is showing you the individual datasets available for a specific job number. `get jobid.n` gets you the n'th file for a jobid. `get TSU00629.3`  gets you the third. If you use `.x` for .n, then you get all spool files, for that jobid, concatenated with a special separator. **It is all in the document that you provided a link for**. I do not know what your actual problem is.

Comment: Maybe is here where my problem is. When I do the second "dir", the FTP retrieves the same information of the first dir.

Comment: Can you edit your question please (link under the question) to include the output you get from the first dir and until the end of the output from the second dir, making sure you include any messages (including normal completion messages)

Comment: Yes, I added @Bill Woodger

Comment: You need to use the jobid, which in your case (quite normal) starts with JOB rather than TSU as in the example. `dir JOB03024` should show you the spool files like in the example you linked to. `get JOB03024.1` will get the first file (the log), `get JOB03024.x` will get you all the files.

Comment: @Bill Woodger, My mistake, I changed it but I still have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the output you show from the example link in your question uses `JESINTERFACELEVEL=2`.

The output you are getting yourself is from using `JESINTERFACELEVEL=1`.

With JESINTERFACELEVEL=1 attempting to list specific details by jobid (TSU-prefix is for a Time Sharing User, so is a TSO session (from where you would be running ISPF), and the JOB prefix is for a batch JOB, for instance a JOB you have submitted through FTP).

The section *JESINTERFACELEVEL differences* in the *Comm Svr: IP User's Guide and Commands* for your level of z/OS details the differences between the two interfacelevels.

Reading the section on *Interfacing with JES* will show you what you can do at which interfacelevel.

Reading the section on * STAtus subcommand--Retrieve status information from a remote host* will show you how to identify the statuslevel you are using.

If you issue the `STAT` command in your FTP session, you will currently get his as one of your 211 messages:

```
211-JESINTERFACELEVEL is 1
```

To change the JESINTERFACELEVEL you need to supply information in the FTP.DATA dataset to override the default value.

Section *Changing local site defaults using FTP.DATA* will explain how to do this, there are a number of options starting with using the `-f` parameter of the FTP invocation.

You should probably consult your Technical Support team at this stage. If you are allowed to use JESINTERFACELEVE=2, they will tell you how to use it. If you are not allowed to use it, you shouldn't attempt to do so on your own.

Comment: Hello @Bill Woodger, I couldn't try this. System support does not like jobs executions through FTP. My JESINTERFACELEVEL is 1 and reading the manual for those level, must be the correct answer. Thanks!